# Could an adult theoretically use a laptop while driving in Oregon if it was controlling an amateur radio station?

Tags: driving, oregon, radio, adult

[ORS 811.507](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_811.507) seems to indicate that an adult with an amateur radio license could legally use a laptop while driving, as long as it was used solely to control an amateur radio station. Obviously this is a very bad idea and nobody should do this, but is it technically legal? If it isn't illegal as distracted driving, would it be reckless driving? I would be very surprised if this was legal, but I don't see any law that would prohibit it.

Comment: Which subparagraph leads you to believe that?

Comment: @MichaelHall subparagraph 4d. I'm sure the purpose is to allow ham operators to use microphones and possibly Morse code keys, but it doesn't specify that.

Comment: (4)(d) deals with cops, firefighters, etc, and doesn't mention laptops.  And I didn't see laptops anywhere else...

Comment: Basically there are three main types of ham radio activity. Phone (talking on a radio, like CB), CW (Morse code; radiotelegraphy), and digital. Digital modes use computers in the same way phone modes use microphones and CW uses a telegraph key; it is the device used to generate the signal that is transmitted. It is an affirmative defense to a prosecution of a person under this section that the person:... Was 18 years of age or older, held a valid amateur radio operator license issued or any other license issued by the Federal Communications Commission and was operating an amateur radio;

Comment: With digital modes, the computer (often a laptop) is being used to operate an amateur radio transceiver.

Comment: @MichaelHall oops, it's (4)(e). Sorry about that.

Comment: I thought it might be, but wanted to confirm.  I cannot answer, but looking at the context of the other examples I think it's safe to presume the intent is to allow a person to key a radio mic and speak.  (Like a CB radio used by a truck driver)  Sending Morse code or operating your ham station via laptop doesn't pass the common sense understanding of using a two way radio.

Comment: Yes, I think it is clear that the intent is not to allow laptop use while driving. Does the fact that that was not the legislature's intent mean the defence does not apply in this case? Regardless, since this is reckless driving, it's illegal anyway (which is definitely a good thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

But they would not be guilty of breaking that particular law.

However, I’m sure Oregon has laws against negligent and reckless driving. This is both.